# Trying to install specific gcc/g++ version on OpenSuse Leap 42.3

Tags: opensuse, gcc

I am using a docker container base image for opensuse/leap:42.3, I want to install c,c++ compiler, and I use the command

`zypper install gcc7-g++`

This does not install the gcc binary, but if I do

```
zypper install gcc-g++
```

gcc is installed although an older version of the compiler version 4.8.5 to be specific
what is the reason for this? Is it because the existing libc libraries on the machine don't support a newer compiler?